# how google gadget refresh or reload itself

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-gadget

I am working on a google gadget for stocks and wondering how to code (Javascript) to refresh the gadget itself every second to get the latest stock quotes from google finance.

Is there any built-in function for it from google gadget api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the standard window.setInterval() and window.clearInterval() Javascript functions, I presume you still get access to the DOM even within a Google Gadget. Something like this:

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() { /*your code to refresh here*/ },
  1000 //1 second in milliseconds);

//Do this to stop the function running if necessary...
window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```